# Setting rate on AudioUnit subtype kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to get/set the rate of an AudioUnit with subtype `kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch`.

The audio unit is added to an `AUGraph`, through an `AUNode`, which has the following component description:

```
acd->componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
acd->componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_NewTimePitch;
acd->componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
```

According to `AudioUnitParameters.h`, get/set the rate should be as simple as get/set the rate parameter on the audio unit.

```
// rate control.
// Global, rate, 1/32 -> 32.0, 1.0
kNewTimePitchParam_Rate                         = 0,
```

However, while setting the value seems no problem (no error is returned) getting the value yields a `OSStatus` with value `-10878 (kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter)`.

Here is how I set the value :

```
- (void)setTempo:(float)value {
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    err = AudioUnitSetParameter(tempoUnit, kNewTimePitchParam_Rate, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, (Float32)value, 0);
    if (err != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Could not set tempo unit rate: %d", err);
    } // no error
}
```

and how I (try to) get it :

```
- (float)tempo {
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    Float32 value = 1.0;
    err = AudioUnitGetParameter(tempoUnit, kNewTimePitchParam_Rate, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &value);
    if (err != noErr) {  // -10878
        NSLog(@"Could not get tempo unit rate: %d", err);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The input of the node is connected to a mixer node, and the output to the RemoteIO unit.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the type of the Audio Unit was wrong.

I changed for `kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter` for the type and kept the same subtype.

Both get/set the tempo now works as expected.

I'm still unclear about why I didn't get any error, neither on setting up the audio unit, nor when setting the value for the rate.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct but comments and answers are welcome :)